# How create LocalNotification on a System Application in a jailbroken device iOS 8

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, jailbreak

I'm making a application for **jailbroken devices**, and my application is in /**System/AppForTest** for example.

I tried to use **UILocalNotification** like usually with no success. The same code is working in a normal application. In a normal application first prompt dialog for Accept notifications from the app, but in a system application the prompt never shows.

Pulling notifications manually could help too. Any help?

Best regards!!!